# Angular material table component not showing data

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm struggling to load data inside my angular material table. The columnheaders show as expected except there are now rows of data. The weird thing is that there is data in the data source that is used by the table. See the code (or images) below:

***Object type to populate datasource***

```
export default interface UserStripeTableResource {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
    saldo: number;
    totalstripes: number;
}
```

This is the interface used to populate the list for the table, no weird things I think.

***Component (.ts file)***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-editsaldo',
  templateUrl: './admin-editsaldo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-editsaldo.component.css']
})
export class AdminEditsaldoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() allusersstripes: UserStripeTableResource[];
  @Output() RefreshListOfUsers = new EventEmitter<any>();


  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserStripeTableResource> = new MatTableDataSource();
  dataDisplayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'fullName', 'saldo', 'totalstripes'];

  selectedamount: number = null;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange): void {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.allusersstripes);
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
  }
```

The file that handles the logic for populating the table. As you can see the data is provided by a parent provider (see @input). The data is immediately assigned to the datasource in the ngOnInit. Also the columns are specified correctly, as they are shown on the html page.

***HTML Page***

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Naam </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fullName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="saldo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Saldo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.saldo}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="totalstripes">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Totaal strepen </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.totalstripes}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dataDisplayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dataDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

The html page that should show the table. The columns match the names specified in the .ts file and are the same as the object properties.

[Image showing html page with datasource log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe3nv.png)

Things that I already tried:

1. Double checking if every needed module was imported correctly.
2. Using ngIf before rendering the table, to make sure the datasource is populated before the table is being rendered.
3. Print out the datasource as JSON straight on html page, to double check if it is there before the table is rendered.
4. Try with the given example from angular material site itself, that's working (but it uses static data so not really comparable I guess)
5. Try ngIf on in parent component on child component, to make sure the async data is there before the component is actually rendered.

I'm really out of ideas, already struggling a couple a days on this. I really hope that someone can help me out :).

[The html source (with no custom css source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLono.png)

***List of packages used***

```
brandfonds-website@0.0.0 E:\Prive Projecten\Coding\Brandfonds\Brandfonds-Frontend
├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
├── @angular/animations@11.1.0
├── @angular/cdk@11.1.0
├── @angular/cli@11.1.1
├── @angular/common@11.1.0
├── @angular/compiler-cli@11.1.0
├── @angular/compiler@11.1.0
├── @angular/core@11.1.0
├── @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33
├── @angular/forms@11.1.0
├── @angular/language-service@11.1.0
├── @angular/localize@11.1.0
├── @angular/material@11.1.0
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.1.0
├── @angular/platform-browser@11.1.0
├── @angular/router@11.1.0
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.2
├── @full-fledged/alerts@11.0.0
├── @types/chart.js@2.9.30
├── @types/jasmine@3.3.16
├── @types/jasminewd2@2.0.8
├── @types/node@8.9.5
├── animate.css@4.1.1
├── chart.js@2.9.4
├── codelyzer@5.2.2
├── font-awesome@4.7.0
├── hammerjs@2.0.8
├── jasmine-core@3.4.0
├── jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
├── karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.6
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
├── karma-jasmine@2.0.1
├── karma@5.1.1
├── ng-swagger-gen@2.3.0
├── protractor@7.0.0
├── rxjs@6.6.3
├── ts-node@7.0.1
├── tslib@2.1.0
├── tslint@6.1.3
├── typescript@4.0.5
└── zone.js@0.11.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I [reproduced your example in a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cdploh) with the latest angular 11 version and it seems to work.

Edit:

ngOnInit gets calld once with null/undefined data because the http request is still in progress. The input data gets updated, but since there is no OnChanges interface implemented, the AdminEditsaldoComponent does nothing with the new data.

The **solution** is to either **implement the OnChanges interface** or to hide the AdminEditsaldoComponent in the parent component until you have loaded the data (<app-admin-editsaldo *ngIf="data" [allusersstripes]="data">...)

Comment: Well I really don't get it then. I have almost the same code, except I receive my data in the "parent component" from a sync http get, but that shouldn't make a difference. Could it maybe have something to do with one of my packages (maybe conflicting or something like that?).

Comment: Maybe it's just CSS, did you check whether the <tr> html element tags exist? You have a scrollbar in the linked image, so it looks like there is content.

Comment: No, that's also not it. I have used no custom css as for as I can tell, I added the html source from chrome in the original post (maybe you see something I don't)?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, no clue why I didn't see it yesterday. I just simulated the async get with a timeout. Your problem is that you propagate null to the component from the parent component on init, then load data async and propagate that again, but ngOnInit is only called once in AdminEditsaldoComponent after the component has been created. What you are missing is the implementation of the OnChanges interface (ngOnChanges) or you *ngIf the <app-admin-editsaldo> tag in the parent component until you have data.
I updated my example to reflect the changes.

Comment: I forgot to say that I had already tried both solutions (that's why you still see the ngchanges in the screenshot). I also put an *ngIf in the parent component html for the child component, but still the same result. Something tells me that it must be a problem with the html itself or maybe my packages. I use fxFlex as a container grid, maybe that clashes somehow? I will update my things that I have tried list btw, sorry for forgetting to add this one.